# Имитация комбинации "Shift + Enter" js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отменил действие по умолчанию на комбанацию `ctrl + z` и нужно что-бы по этой комбинации делался перевод строки в поле для ввода. Я это делаю добавлением `<br>` но впечатление, что комбинация срабатывает не каждый раз и главное что нет перевода строки...каретка остаётся на той же строке...Как её перекинуть на строку ниже?)

Демо http://jsfiddle.net/p00oh4sf/6/

P.S. другими словами нужен результат который происходит при нажатии `shift + enter`.
Может можно как-то при нажатии на `ctrl + z` сэмулировать нажатие `shift + enter` ...

Comment: Нажатие Shift+Enter добавляет дополнительный <br> перед курсором. Курсором нужно управлять вручную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы нормально функционировать, в contenteditable должен быть как минимум один перенос. Его можно добавить при первом нажатии, или сразу в DOM.

Для управления курсором, нужно использовать Selection API

```js
var el = document.getElementById("editable");

el.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
el.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (e.which !== 90 || !e.ctrlKey) return;
  var selection = window.getSelection(),
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
    br = document.createElement('br');
  range.deleteContents(); // удаляем, если что-то было выделено
  range.insertNode(br); // вставляем перенос за текущим положением курсора
  range.setStartAfter(br); // переносим курсор за перенос
  range.setEndAfter(br);
  range.collapse(false);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);  
});
```

```html
<div id=editable contenteditable> 123 <br/></div>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое)